# Migrate 1.6.0.0 to 2.0.7 - admin 404 after migrating settings

Tags: admin-panel, 404-page, magento2-migration-tool

I just installed a fresh Magento 2.0.7 (web installer) on a local server (Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu), PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.4, mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.30)

After the installation Magento frontend and backend have been working fine. 
I created a mysql dump and a backup of the whole folder.

Then I went on:

```
sudo -u www-data composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool
sudo -u www-data composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.0.7
sudo -u www-data php bin/magento migrate:settings /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.6.0.0/config.xml
```

Migration ran smooth:

```
[INFO][mode: settings][stage: volume check][step: Stores Step]: Migration completed
```

Then I reloaded my admin panel with F5 and I get a 404.
`dev.url.com/index.php/admin`
results into a 404 as well.
`dev.url.com/search/term/popular`
etc. are all working, so I assume it's not `.htaccess` - still, my virtual host directory settings:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/dev.url.com>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

In the database table `core_config_data` of Magento 2.0.7 now, I can see the settings from 1.6.0 - so I assume the migration ran smooth and now I need to figure out why I can't access my admin panel anymore.

`admin/url/custom` is set to admin as well as in `app/etc/env.php`

So I tried those:

```
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

But I still can't access my admin panel.

The apache log isn't helpful:

> "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 404
>   "GET /index.php/admin HTTP/1.1" 404
>   "GET /index.php/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404

and there is nothing in `var/log/system.log` or `var/log/debug.log`

That problem doesn't seem to be uncommon but what I found online is mostly related to .htaccess / mod_rewrite - but both seem to be working fine here (before the migration I was able to access all pages and in the frontend I still am).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your .htaccess file to this content present on the original file, if it work well you can filter and add your custom params separately.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/.htaccess